# HTML audio.currentTime не меняется в Google Crome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web-audio

Доброго времени суток.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, `audio.currentTime` сбрасывается в  `0`, если принудительно менять ему значение. Причем, только в **Google Chrome (57.0.2987.133 (64-bit))**.

Вот кусок кода на JS:

```
Player.prototype.setCurrentTime = function(percentage) {
    var playing = this.isPlaying();
    if (playing) {
        this.audio.pause();
        temporaryPaused = true;
    }
    var newTime = parseInt(percentage * this.maxTime / 100, 10);
    if (this.debug) {
        _trace("Start setting current time to " + newTime + " ms");
    }
    var audio = this.audio;
    audio.currentTime = Boolean(newTime) ? newTime : 0;
    var canPlayListener = audio.addEventListener("seeked", function() {
        if (playing && temporaryPaused) {
            audio.play();
            temporaryPaused = false;
            if (this.debug) {
                _trace("Current time updated to " + audio.currentTime + " ms");
            }
        }
        audio.removeEventListener("seeked", canPlayListener);
    });
};
```

Результат в Хроме:

```
"Start setting current time to 34 ms"
"Current time updated to 0 ms"
```

Comment: Похожая проблема - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351252/i-can-get-audio-currenttime-but-not-set-it-in-google-chrome

Comment: Пишут, что может быть проблема в формате аудио.